# How could you convert the following recursion with dynamic programming?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

How would you convert the following recursive program with dynamic programming (DP)?
I'm just having a little trouble trying to redefine this code into a dynamic programming form. I got the base case and the general case identified, and I am aware that DP is about a "bottom-up" approach.

```
int add(int, int);

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    printf("Enter positive integers x, y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    printf("Result: %d\n", add(x, y));

    return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
    if(x < 0 || y < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Negative Integer received!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (x == 1 || y == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return add(x, y-1) + add(x - 1, y) + add(x-1, y-1);
}
```

Comment: Does the recursion actually terminate there? Seems like `add(x, y, z + 1)` will keep it going forever.

Comment: DP can be either top-down or bottom-up. Top-down is still recursive, just with caching of previous results from the function. But you need to fix your recursion first as Ryan says.

Comment: I did a little edit to the number of parameters and the recursion. Can this be converted into dp?

Comment: you didn't declare `add()` before use, so it'll use variable default promotion rule with variable number of arguments. And `add(x, y-1, )` won't compile

Comment: `return add(x, y-1, ) + add(x - 1, y) + add(x-1, y-1);` is invalid C code.  Most clear to post true code.

Comment: I agree with chux, but here an advice, recursive function use stack, so is you want to do without recursion you need to do simulate a stack.

Comment: What is the range of valid values of `x,y`?  Certainly negative values result in a stack overflow.  What is the range code needs to successfully run?  This adds clarity.

Comment: Thank you for the advice people. As you've mentioned, I have edited the code to handle the negative integer cases to avoid stack overflow.

Comment: Additional question; what would you do to convert a recursive algorithm into a dp algorithm in such cases? (considering different cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do it in recursive way? There is an iterative way, and iterative 'almost always' beats recursive. Besides it is less code:

```
int DP[500][500];
memset(DP, 0, sizeof(DP));
for(int i=1; i<=x; i++) DP[i][1] = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=y; i++) DP[1][i] = 1;

for(int i=2; i<=x; i++) {
    for(int j=2; j<=y; j++) {
        DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j-1] + DP[i-1][j] + DP[i][j-1];
    }
}

printf("Result: %d\n", DP[x][y]);
```

But if you insist on recursion you can pass your DP array to function by pointer. And every time check if you calculated DP[i][j] before, if so don't calculate it again and return back:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void add(int x, int y, int (*M)[500])
{
    if(M[x][y] > 0) return;

    if (x == 1 || y == 1) {
        M[x][y] = 1;
        return;
    }

    add(x, y-1, M);
    add(x - 1, y, M);
    add(x-1, y-1, M);

    M[x][y] = M[x][y-1] + M[x-1][y] + M[x-1][y-1];
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Enter x, y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    int DP[500][500];
    memset(DP, 0, sizeof(DP));
    add(x, y, DP);

    printf("Result: %d\n", DP[x][y]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will cause stack overflow for all the possible x,y and z integer(negative, positive) combinations

Comment: What if I reduce the number of parameters to two?? Like add(x, y)?

Comment: I have edited the code so it won't cause overflow error. Then will this work as dp?

Comment: Again you are wrong here, what if x=-1 and y = -1, Your code will cause stack overflow

Comment: If I assume the x and y to be a positive integer, and handle the negative integer cases separately, will that solve the stack overflow issue you are talking about?

Comment: Now your code handles all the edge cases perfectly, But Mathematically still your code gives wrong answer. For example inputs x=2 y=2 your code gives output 3 where as actual sum of 2+2=4